# Load metadata from https with Spring SAML

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

I'd like to import some metadata from the web, by using the **https** protocol:

```
@Bean
public HTTPMetadataProvider ssoCircleMetadataProvider()
        throws MetadataProviderException {
    String metadataURL = "https://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml";
    final Timer backgroundTaskTimer = new Timer(true);
    HTTPMetadataProvider provider = new HTTPMetadataProvider(
            backgroundTaskTimer, httpClient(), metadataURL);
    provider.setParserPool(parserPool());
    return provider;
}
```

By reading the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-https), I found this step:

> By default loading of metadata using the HTTP-based provider over
>   HTTPS performs trust verification configured in your JDK. In case
>   you'd like to use certificates in your keyStore, add the following
>   bean which changes the socketFactory used by the HTTP Client:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="registerProtocol"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>https</value>
            <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol">
                <constructor-arg value="https"/>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolSocketFactory"/>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg value="443"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Converting in Java Config, it becomes:

```
@Bean
public Protocol httpClientProtocol() {
    org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolSocketFactory factory =
            new org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolSocketFactory();
    Protocol httpClientProtocol = new Protocol ("https", factory, 443);
    return httpClientProtocol;
}

@Bean
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean() {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(Protocol.class);
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("registerProtocol");
    Object[] args = {"https", httpClientProtocol()};
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(args);
    return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
}
```

But the `org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolSocketFactory` class results not found. I'm using the version `1.0.0-RC2` of **Spring SAML**.

Am I doing something wrong?

How can I fix this error and load metadata as desired?

---

**Update**

By using the SNAPSHOT repository, I'm able to use the TLSProtocolSocketFactory class.
I've imported into my keystore the certificate of SSOCircle, but despite that, the application returns an error as follows:

```
[2014-07-31 17:33:27.596] boot - 11800 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] --- HTTPMetadataProvider:    Error retrieving metadata from https://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

---

**Update 2**

I've fix my code according to your suggestion. I've imported all certs into the keystore, but on boot  the application returns this error:

```
[2014-08-01 10:02:38.961] boot - 14704 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] --- BasicX509CredentialNameEvaluator: Supplied trusted names are null or empty, skipping name evaluation
[2014-08-01 10:02:38.962] boot - 14704 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] --- MetadataCredentialResolver: Attempting PKIX path validation on untrusted credential: [subjectName='CN=ADFS Signing - ststest-vdenotarisnet.vdenotaris.it']
[2014-08-01 10:02:39.028] boot - 14704 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] --- MetadataCredentialResolver: PKIX path construction failed for untrusted credential: [subjectName='CN=ADFS Signing - ststest-vdenotarisnet.vdenotaris.it']: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[2014-08-01 10:02:39.028] boot - 14704 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] --- PKIXSignatureTrustEngine: Signature trust could not be established via PKIX validation of signing credential
[2014-08-01 10:02:39.028] boot - 14704 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] --- BaseSignatureTrustEngine: Failed to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
[2014-08-01 10:02:39.028] boot - 14704 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] --- BaseSignatureTrustEngine: Failed to verify signature and/or establish trust using any KeyInfo-derived credentials
[2014-08-01 10:02:39.029] boot - 14704 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] --- PKIXSignatureTrustEngine: PKIX validation of signature failed, unable to resolve valid and trusted signing key
[2014-08-01 10:02:39.029] boot - 14704 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] --- SignatureValidationFilter: Signature trust establishment failed for metadata entry http://ststest.vdenotaris.local/adfs/services/trust
[2014-08-01 10:02:39.031] boot - 14704 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] --- AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider: Error filtering metadata from https://ststest.vdenotaris.local/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilterException: Signature trust establishment failed for metadata entry
```

Note that the used cert is verified by GoDaddy.

Comment: Start your application with -Djavax.net.debug=all and let's see what it says - the log trace should include more details on why does the PKIX fail. Any chance your certificate is expired? Please double check you have imported the correct key to the samlKeystore.jks

Comment: Btw I have simplified the configuration, once you update to later version the only thing you need to do is include bean of class org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer

Comment: The import was done right, I'm sure about that. The certification is still valid. I'll check soon the app by providing the javax.net debug option as suggested.

Comment: I'm sure that the import is now right, that wasn't my point - I made the TLSProtocolConfigurer  to simplify it for people who will be trying to configure the same in the future, and wanted to warn you that you will have to reconfigure once you update.

Comment: Where could I find related doc?

Comment: It will be in the tomorrow's nightly build.

Comment: Did you get this resolved V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TLSProtocolSocketFactory` class is only available in the trunk and will be part of 1.0.0.FINAL. The only choice in RC2 is to add keys to the JDK's keystore.

**Update:**

Snapshot versions of Spring SAML are available in this repository:

```
<repository>
  <releases>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <id>com.springsource.repository.maven.snapshot</id>
  <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Maven Repository - SpringSource Snapshot Releases</name>
  <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
</repository>
```

You might want to read the "What's new" chapter which lists changes since RC2, some of them with implications for backward compatibility.

**Another update:**

Your initialization is wrong, the TLSFactory needs to be started as a bean, you probably also need a dependency in MetadataManager.

```
@Bean
public ProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory() {
    return new TLSProtocolSocketFactory();
}

@Bean
public Protocol socketFactoryProtocol() {
    return new Protocol("https", socketFactory(), 443);
}

@Bean
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean socketFactoryInitialization() {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(Protocol.class);
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("registerProtocol");
    Object[] args = {"https", socketFactoryProtocol()};
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(args);
    return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("metadata")
@DependsOn("socketFactoryInitialization")
public CachingMetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException, IOException     {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the trunk via Maven?

Comment: I switched to 1.0.0.RC3-SNAPSHOT, but that class is still missing.

Comment: The class is here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/trust/httpclient/TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java and also here in nightly build http://repo.spring.io/list/snapshot/org/springframework/security/extensions/spring-security-saml2-core/1.0.0.RC3-SNAPSHOT/spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.0.RC3-20140731.060022-518.jar, you either have wrong version or the problem's somewhere else, perhaps the exception has more information?

Comment: There was a problem with my Nexus server. It seems to be ok now.

Comment: I've just another question: does this procedure work also with self-signed certificates?

Comment: I update the question by reporting an error about the certification.